# Big O: Is this FOR loop O(n log(n)) or O(log(n)^2)?

Tags: performance, runtime, big-o

I have a generic function

```
for i from 1 to n; i = 2i; {
    for j from 1 to i; {
        (constant time stuff)
    }
}
```

For this function, the first line `for i from 1 to n; i = 2i;` I know is O(log(n)). The line `(constant time stuff)` is irrelevant so who cares since it's O(1).

But the middle line `for j from 1 to i;` is where I'm having trouble.

I'm assuming that the Big O of this line is the same as the first, since it's following the same pattern as the first where the i is doubled after each iteration, which would make it O(log(n)), but could it also be O(n)?

Also, if it is in fact O(log(n)) * O(log(n)), that's just O(log(n)^2) correct?

Sorry, I just started this Big O stuff and unfortunately I've had to rely on the internet so far since my teacher isn't very good :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this FOR loop O(n log(n)) or O(log(n)^2)?

Neither.

The outer loop iterates `log n` times. If the inner loop had the same number of iterations each time, we could then just multiply the number of iterations of the outer loop by the number of operations of the inner loop. But it doesn't, so we can't.

Instead we actually need to sum up the number of iterations of the inner loop: The first time, it iterates one time. The second time, two times. Then four, then eight and so on until it finally reaches `n`. So we have the sum `1 + 2 + 4 + ... + n` where we know that the sum has `log n` summands, in other words the sum from `k=0` to `n` of `2^k`. This sum happens to be equal to `2n-1`. `2n-1` is clearly in `O(n)`, so that's your answer.

Comment: Ok, so the middle loop is `O(n)`, or are you saying that that's the final answer to the Big O complexity of the whole function?

Because I thought you take the length of time of the outer loop, `O(log(n))` in this case, times the complexity of the inner loop. So wouldn't it be `O(n) * O(log(n)) = O(n log(n))`?

Comment: @ESM I'm saying that's the complexity of the whole function.

Comment: Why isn't it n*log(n)? isn't that the worst case over O(n)?

Comment: @ESM The complexity of the inner loop isn't `O(n)`, it's `O(i)` and `O(log n) * O(i)` makes no sense because `i` changes on each iteration. That's what I meant by "If the inner loop had the same number of iterations each time, we could then just multiply the number of iterations of the outer loop by the number of operations of the inner loop. But it doesn't, so we can't."

Comment: Ok so just to check if I'm understanding this correctly, let's say the first loop line read: `for i from 1 to 2^n; i = 2i; {`

Then that would mean that the inner loop complexity would be `O((2^n) - 1)`, while the first would be just `O(2^n)`, which would equal a total complexity of `O(2^n)` because `O(2^(n+1) - 1` simplifies.

Am I making correct sense of this?

Comment: @ESM If you didn't change anything about the inner loop, the complexity of the inner loop would still be `O(i)`. You can't really reason about the inner loop's complexity in a vacuum when its number of iterations depends on the outer loop. But yes, the complexity of the whole thing would be `O(2^n)`.

Comment: ohh ok, I think I understand it a bit better now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Abusing notation a bit, you have

```
  sum_{i=1..log n} ( sum_{j=1..2^i} O(1) )
= sum_{i=1..log n} (2^i * O(1))
= O(2^(log n + 1))
= O(n)
```

The second but last equivalence can be proven by an easy induction:

```
  2^(n+1) 
= 2 * 2^n
= 2 * (sum_{i=0..n-1} (2^i) + 1)
= sum_{i=1..n} (2^i) + 2
= sum_{i=0..n} (2^i) + 1
```

with base case `n=1: 2^1 = 1+1 = 2^0+1`.